# Yii2 - array with URL:s in listView

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

I have an array, Vehicles, "id" and "vehicle", like this database table:

```
Vehicles
1.Car
2.Truck
3.Bicycle
4.Motorcycle
```

I make a model of the table, and CRUD it, I am given this generated code in `vehicle/index`:

```
<?= ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'itemOptions'  => ['class' => 'item'],
    'itemView'     => function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
        return Html::a(Html::encode($model->vehicle), ['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    },
]) ?>
```

I see now a list with all my vehicles as links:

```
Car,
Truck,
Bicycle,
Motorcycle
```

What I want, is the links to get me somewhere, like this:

```
Car     - vehicles/car,
Truck   - vehicles/truck
...etc
```

I will have to hard-code the paths, I guess.
Is there a convenient way to do this, in the Html::a function given above?
Or should I use another type of function?

Comment: Add one more column to Vehicles table as 'path'. Use this field in 'URL' field of your HTML:a tag.

Comment: Thank you. That option came to my mind, too...not a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the urlManager

```
return Html::a(Html::encode($model->vehicle),
       ['/your-controller/your-action', 'id' => $model->id]);
```

assuming your controller is  name vehicle  and in $model->name you have  car, or Trukck ...

```
     return Html::a(Html::encode($model->vehicle),
       ['/vehicle/'. $model->name, 'id' => $model->id]);
```

Comment: Thank you. Will give it a test!